# How to find out what theme are used for AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light" in my app. And when I want custom style of some global element(button, floating action button, cardview, etc.), I open design mode of desired element in layout and I can see what theme are used for specific element, then I go to Theme.MaterialComponents.Light, search for the theme, add it to my own theme(which overrides Theme.MaterialComponents.Light), make my own theme based on that and override it in the application theme. How to do it globally for AlertDialog? I know that if I create it I can specify the theme in the invoke of AlertDialog.Builder. But what if some third-party library generates it and I'm unable to change its invoke? How to force everything to use one custom theme, like I do it with views? I tried to find the theme that's responsible for that, but didn't succeed. I overwrote that(I'll attach it below), but it doesn't work.

```
//Base application theme
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    //Are they responsible for AlertDialogs or I'm wrong?
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
</style>

//My custom theme, which doesn't override global AlertDialogs
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Base colors -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#EEEEEE</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">#FFF</item>

    <!-- Button styles -->
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/YDialogPositiveButton</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/YDialogNegativeButton</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/YDialogNeutralButton</item>

    <!-- Sizes -->
    <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/YDialogTitleTextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

Comment: By doesn't work, do you mean nothing happens in any of your dialogs, or is the problem only with third party dialogs? Maybe the library you're using doesn't use the MaterialComponents theme.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Nothing happens even in my own AlertDialogs. And saying "third-party library" I mean this one(AmbilWarna Color Picker) https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna. I looked into source code and it doesn't specify any theme. And I found out one thing: when I change "primaryColor" attribute in my base application theme, it applies to buttons in every AlertDialog(including third part color picker dialog). Actually. that's exactly what I wanna change(buttons' text color), because I need "primaryColor" for another goals.

Comment: `materialAlertDialog` is only used with the MaterialAlertDialog class, not AlertDialog. I'm not sure why the `alertDialogTheme` isn't being applied, though. By the way, you may want it to use a `ThemeOverlay` as its parent, so it will absorb all the top level theme attributes you have set and don't want to have to redundantly set in the dialog theme.

Comment: @Tenfour04 not applying custom style in my own alertdialogs is my bad, actually. There are many nested styles I didn't notice. But I'm curious why it doesn't apply to color picker dialog.

Comment: I see the problem. You're probably using `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog` for your own dialogs, while the library is using the framework `android.app.AlertDialog`, so they are resolving different themes for the dialog. The appcompat AlertDialog uses `alertDialogTheme` and the framework AlertDialog uses `android:alertDialogTheme`. It could be tricky to design a theme that works with both since AppCompat redefines a bunch of stuff. You might want to look for a different color picker library that uses AppCompat, or that at least lets you pass a style resource to its constructor.